# how to print trees onto console?

Tags: console, tree, binary-tree

it would be nice if i could print the binary search trees i am writing onto python console ? any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
def printTree(tree, depth = 0):
    if tree == None or len(tree) == 0:
        print "\t" * depth, "-"
    else:
        for key, val in tree.items():
            print "\t" * depth, key
            printTree(val, depth+1)
```

(*Source: http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/91*)

This method will yield:

```
n1
    n2
        n4
        n5
    n3
        n6
        n7
```

You can go along these lines and prettify as necessary.